# HoughLinesP not detecting lines OpenCV android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am working with OpenCV 3.0 for Android. I have an image in which i want to detect angle of hands inside circular dials. for that i am working on `HoughLinesP` to detect hands.
Here is the code.

```
Mat imgSource = new Mat(), imgCirclesOut = new Mat(),imgLinesOut=new Mat();
//grey opencv
Imgproc.cvtColor(Image, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.GaussianBlur( imgSource, imgSource, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2 );

int threshold = 0;
int minLineSize = 0;
int lineGap = 0;

Imgproc.HoughLinesP(imgSource, imgLinesOut, 1, Math.PI/180, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);
for( int j = 0; i < imgLinesOut.cols(); i++ )
{
    double[] vec=imgLinesOut.get(0,j);
    Point pt1, pt2;
    pt1=new Point(vec[0],vec[1]);
    pt2=new Point(vec[2],vec[3]);
    Imgproc.line( Image, pt1, pt2, new Scalar(0,0,255), 3, Core.LINE_AA,0);
}
```

But result is
[image]

What i need is the angle of hands in these circles. Any help regarding this issue is highly appreciated. Thanks in ADvance

**Edit**
I have updated my code with this

```
 Mat imgSource = new Mat(), imgCirclesOut = new Mat(),imgLinesOut=new Mat();

 Imgproc.GaussianBlur( Image, imgSource, new Size(5, 5), 2, 2 );      
 int threshold = 20;
 int minLineSize = 0;
 int lineGap = 10;
 Imgproc.Canny(imgSource, imgSource, 70, 100);
 Imgproc.HoughLinesP(imgSource, imgLinesOut, 1, Math.PI/180, threshold, minLineSize, lineGap);
for( int j = 0; j < imgLinesOut.cols(); j++ )
{
    double[] vec=imgLinesOut.get(0,j);

    Point pt1, pt2;
    pt1=new Point(vec[0],vec[1]);
    pt2=new Point(vec[2],vec[3]);

    Imgproc.line( imgSource, pt1, pt2, new Scalar(0,0,255), 3, Core.LINE_AA,0);
}
```

as suggested by @Micka, there is no need of Graying image(I removed `cvtcolor`). I also decreased value of `GuassianBlur` Size to `5`. I have added Canny on image too for edges.

Resulting blur image is

[image]

Comment: did you try `Math.PI/1800` ?

Comment: @Micka `math.PI/1800` shifted line from last circle to second one...

Comment: your problem probably is this line: `for( int j = 0; i < imgLinesOut.cols(); i++ )` which should be changed to `for( int j = 0; j < imgLinesOut.cols(); j++ )`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this silly mistake @Micka but this didn't fixed the issue. Blue line is now in 4th circle now...

Comment: you shouldnt provide a grayscale image to the function but a binary edge image (edges = white, non-edges = black). Please try to compute `canny` and send the result as input to HoughLinesP. If your image is the real size, gaussian blur of size 9 seems a little bit too big, too. Can you add the blurred image to your post? When you compute canny, please post the canny image, too.

Comment: @Micka i have updated my code. Kindly check edit Secion. Thanks

Comment: `Imgproc.GaussianBlur( Image, imgSource, new Size(5, 5), 2, 2 );` is wrong I guess. Should be sth like `Imgproc.GaussianBlur( imgSource, imgSource, new Size(5, 5), 2, 2 );`, although for that image size filter size 5 might still be too big

Comment: Post the original image, and the expected result, so we can actually try your code

Comment: @Miki i have first image as input and want to get the angle or values written on meter/dials as output... Hope my point is clear now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Detecting lines can be a problem in such small images, since you have to few points to fill the Hough accumulator properly.

I propose to use a different approach:

1. Segment each circle (dial)
2. Extract the largest dark blob (hand)

Below is a simple implementation of this idea. The code is in C++, but you can easily port to Java, or at least use as a reference.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    Mat3b res;
    cvtColor(img, res, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    // Find dials
    vector<Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(img, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, img.cols/10, 400, 40);

    // For each dial
    for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); ++i)
    {

        // Segment the dial
        Mat1b dial(img.size(), uchar(255));
        Mat1b mask(img.size(), uchar(0));
        circle(mask, Point(circles[i][0], circles[i][1]), circles[i][2], Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);
        img.copyTo(dial, mask);

        // Apply threshold and open
        Mat1b bin;
        threshold(dial, bin, 127, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(5,5));
        morphologyEx(bin, bin, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

        // Get min area rect
        vector<Point> points;
        findNonZero(bin, points);
        RotatedRect r = minAreaRect(points);

        // Draw min area rect
        Point2f pts[4];
        r.points(pts);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            line(res, pts[j], pts[(j + 1) % 4], Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
        }       
    }

    imshow("Result", res);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Starting from this image:

[image]

I find *hands* here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Miki, Your solution worked. I had to remove `CircleHough` and masking part. Applied threshold and open on image, getting contours and looping around that object did the trick. Thanks again :)

Comment: This is a good start to read the gauge meter for my project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45215212/read-a-gauge-meter-in-python but just a question: How have I to read the "value" of the gauge? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
for( int j = 0; j < imgLinesOut.size(); j++ )
```

This will give the size of the vector.To iterate through that vector